# Unable to update eclipse because of conflicting dependency

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-11.10

I've taken a screen shot of the problem for your convenience. It doesn't let me upload it here because I'm a new user. so here's the link: http://s9.postimage.org/9bmz08snj/Screenshot_at_2012_01_30_15_18_07.png

I'm having trouble updating Eclipse. This happened after installing the android sdk and the ADT plugin. I am unable to do any of these individually. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There's not enough detail visible in that screenshot to know where the dependency conflict is coming from (what plugin(s) versions are conflicting).

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the linux notes on this page: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Yeah I did. As a matter of fact it helped me resolve the original problem I was having by installing the ia32-libs.